# jquery detach(): [object Object] has no method 'replace'

Tags: javascript, jquery

*Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'*  to be precise. The code:

```
var controls = $('#head_hidden').children().eq(0);
var item_mouse_over = function() {
    $(this).append(controls);
}
var item_mouse_leave = function() {
    $(this).detach(controls); //this is the problematic strig
}

$('.item').mouseover(item_mouse_over);
$('.item').mouseleave(item_mouse_leave);
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scythargon/nmWcj/) explanation. With item_mouse_over() I add "controls" to element, but with item_mouse_leave() I could not remove them:(

Comment: and how are you calling this function?  Chances are that your `this` variable is not what you think it is.

Comment: @Alnitak OK, thanks, added calls, any ideas now?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I think you need to explain in plain English what it is you expect to happen. The relevant HTML for `.item` and `#head_hidden` would be good too. What you are currently doing with `append` is you are removing the element the jQuery object `controls` is referencing from the DOM and moving it into back into the DOM into the element referenced by the jQuery wrapper `$(this)`. If after that you want to want to `detach` `controls` again the item will not be moved back but be gone from the DOM and only exist in the jQuery wrapper `controls`. Is that what you expect to actually happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:::is this what you are attempting to do: http://jsfiddle.net/EhzFy/3/

if so then you have to remove the child from the div that it was added to:`$(this).children().eq(0).detach();`

but if all you're trying to accomplish is making the object move from one div to another then try this: http://jsfiddle.net/EhzFy/2/

Comment: @scythargon: I think it mainly came together by eventually obtaining all the required details :)